# Run Time error '13' but only with dates where day is greater or equal to 10. How do I get the code to continuously run throughout the month?

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, excel-2019

I have a VBA script in Workbook A that should copy data from row 2 of Workbook B based on a date inputted into C2.

The script in theory should copy D2:F2 and paste it in the corresponding rows based on the date in D2.

This has worked so far for the entire month, but now the date is greater than 09, the code seems to fall down. I have backtested this for theoretical other months, and the same thing happens, on/after the 10th of every month I get a runtime 13 error.

The reason for 2 different workbooks is to have the data saved in a seperate place/spreadsheet as this needs to be accessed by other departments, who cannot see the inputs for GDPR based reasons. I designed this macro to therefore open the KPITool spreadsheet wherein the data is then linked to my inital workbook (using = cell reference) before being in theory pasted into the correct row, and then the workbook saves and closes.

Here is the code:

```
Sub PasteKPI()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    'OpenWorkbook1
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Workbooks("KPITool.xlsm").Worksheets("KPITotal")
    With ws
        .Range("D2:F2").Copy
        Dim sDate As String: sDate = .Range("C2").Value
        Dim srcDate As Date: srcDate = CDate(Right(sDate, Len(sDate) - InStr(sDate, ",") - 1))
        Dim srcRange As Range: Set srcRange = .Cells.Find(srchDate)
        If Not srcRange Is Nothing Then
            srcRange.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        End If
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = True
    CloseWorkbook1
    Workbooks("InitialWorkbook.xlsm").RefreshAll
End Sub
```

Comment: What are your regional settings set to?

Comment: please add sample data so that we know what you are working with...

Comment: Try removing the `-1` in `Dim srcDate As Date: srcDate = CDate(Right(sDate, Len(sDate) - InStr(sDate, ",") - 1))`

Comment: What's the format of date in `C2`?  When you convert C2 to a real date you put it in the `srcDate` variable, but then use `srchDate` in your find - using [Option Explicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/option-explicit-statement) would have pointed that error out.  Is also worth defining each parameter in `Find` as it remembers what you used last time - even if through the dialog box.